# How to create multiple IAP's in the same app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have an application which contains multiple users in different groups (kinda like life 360). In order to access the full functionality of the app, the user has to pay $5.99 per group per month

I was wondering how can I create multiple auto-renewable subscriptions for the same app? Whenever I try StoreKit and create a dummy purchase, it succeeds but the second time it just restores it.

I have 2 subscriptions in a group right now (monthly and Yearly), I need to be able to purchase the same subscription in every group in my app.
For example, a user opens up group 1 and see a button saying "Buy premium", they purchase the premium for group 1 for $5.99 for 1 month, and switch over to group 2 where they again see the same button saying "Buy premium", and as soon as the user clicks that button, the user should be able to buy the same auto renewable subscription for $5.99 for 1 month, this time, for group 2
How can I achieve this?

Example

[image]

In this image, I purchased Life360 Premium in 2 different circles ( Free trial 1 week )

Comment: You should create 2 different IAP subscriptions to achieve that.

Comment: That's the thing, in my app and life360, the user can create as many groups as they want. So the subscriptions can me more than 1. No max limit

Comment: You would need to create multiple IAPs with the same description but different product codes, say `com.myApp.sub.1`, `com.myApp.sub.2` and so on. Then when they make a purchase you would need to determine which product codes already have active subscriptions and submit the purchase for a higher or unused number.

Comment: @Paulw11 but won't that be also limited in the way that I can only create N number of groups in my app because I have only N number of IAP's. Also, how would this work while purchasing, won't the IAP's in a subscription group replace the older one?

Comment: You can only create "N", but "N" can be a large number; hundreds if you want. They would each need to be in a different subscription group.

Comment: The only other way to do it is use a non-auto renewing subscription.

Comment: I don't know if life 360 has some kind of limit, but it's for sure using an auto-renewing subscription. Can you explain how to do it using your method? I didn't get it that well as to how that would be executed